# How to export sio2 file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

When i export  sio2 file of 3d game on simulator it is loading but then black screen appears.

Even i getting "current frame does not matches this frame" this error.

Can anybody help me out with his problem.

To be more technical while getting material objects its happening so

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code in templateRender as follows

```
void templateRender( void )
{
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    SIO2camera *_SIO2camera = ( SIO2camera * )sio2ResourceGet(
            sio2->_SIO2resource, SIO2_CAMERA, "camera/Camera" );

    if( _SIO2camera )
    {
        // Adjust the perspective, please take not
        // that this operation should only be done
        // once everytime you are switching cameras.
        sio2Perspective( _SIO2camera->fov,
                        sio2->_SIO2window->scl->x / sio2->_SIO2window->scl->y,
                        _SIO2camera->cstart,
                        _SIO2camera->cend );

        // Enter the 3D landscape mode
        sio2WindowEnterLandscape3D();
        {
            sio2CameraRender( _SIO2camera );
            sio2ResourceRender( sio2->_SIO2resource,
                               sio2->_SIO2window,
                               _SIO2camera,
                               SIO2_RENDER_SOLID_OBJECT );
        }

        sio2WindowLeaveLandscape3D();
    }
}
```

Then in `templateLoading`:

```
void templateLoading( void )
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    sio2ResourceCreateDictionary( sio2->_SIO2resource );


    sio2ResourceOpen( sio2->_SIO2resource,
                      "Tutorial1.sio2", 1 );

    while( i != sio2->_SIO2resource->gi.number_entry )
    {
        sio2ResourceExtract( sio2->_SIO2resource, NULL );
        ++i;
    }

    sio2ResourceClose( sio2->_SIO2resource );
    sio2ResourceBindAllMatrix( sio2->_SIO2resource );
    sio2ResourceGenId( sio2->_SIO2resource );
    sio2ResetState();
    sio2->_SIO2window->_SIO2windowrender = templateRender;
}
```